# Is it OK to scale image by changing its resolution?

Tags: graphics, scaling, resolution

Assume I have an image `fruit240.jpg` of 800 pixels by 600 pixels at resolution of 240 dpi.

Normally I can scale it by half using the following way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\parindent=0pt
\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=5pt


\begin{document}
{\color{red}\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fruit240}}}
\end{document}
```

Doubling resolution by invoking ImageMagick's `convert` as follows apparently makes the same effect as scaling by half.

```
convert fruit240.jpg -density 480 fruit480.jpg
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\parindent=0pt
\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=5pt


\begin{document}
{\color{red}\fbox{\includegraphics{fruit480}}}
\end{document}
```

Is it OK to scale image by changing its resolution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, changing the resolution using the `-density` operator in ImageMagick (or through the `Information` window in IrfanView) is a lossless operation. From the [ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=28phmtp1ikca1jtmbu6cjov8b1#density):

> The -density option sets an attribute and does not alter the underlying raster image.

Comment: +1 but up to now, I don't understand why the resolution is defined like that. In my mental model, changing resolution is related to resampling the image. :-)

Comment: The resolution is basically a factor for converting from pixels to physical lengths (like centimetres). If your image is 1000 px wide, and has a resolution of 250 dpi (dots per inch, the same as pixels per inch), then the physical width of the image is going to be 1000 px / 250 dpi = 4 in. If you change the resolution to 500 dpi, the image is still 1000 px wide, but it will now have a physical width of 1000 px / 500 dpi = 2 in. No information is lost in this process.

Comment: @xport: “In my mental model, changing resolution is related to resampling the image.”  That is because you are thinking of the case where you change the resolution _while fixing the physical size (such as 4 in × 3 in)_.  When you tell ImageMagick to change the resolution, it does so _while fixing the size in pixels (such as 1000 px × 750 px)_.

Comment: What is the geometrical form of a single pixel defined in an image file? Is it circular or rectangular?

Comment: @xport: It's rectangular, and if the horizontal and vertical resolutions are equal, which is usually the case, it's square.